# Why is potassium permanganate paramagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, magnetism

$\ce{KMnO4}$ is coloured due to charge transfer spectra. As Mn doesn't have any electrons, it shouldn't be magnetic. But, according to the magnetic susceptibility value given on Wikipedia, it comes out to be paramagnetic. How is it possible?

Comment: Welcome onnnthe ChemSE! Mn has a lot of electrons, about 30. I suggest to clarify this part :-)

Comment: @Cde124AB_ You may mean all Valence electrons are invokved  in bonding and there is none left to be unpaired. It may need MO point of view. Even O2 does not seem to be paramagnetic by simple valence electrons inventory.

Comment: Good question. Please see my comment at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115841/magnetic-properties-of-potassium-dichromate#comment218490_115841 If I have time I will turn that into an answer. The reason is not trivial.