# Magnetic behaviour of potassium permanganate

Tags: magnetism

I was going through the properties of potassium permanganate and found this-

> It has two physical properties of considerable interest: its intense color and  its  diamagnetism  along  with  temperature-dependent  weak paramagnetism.

My teacher said that the intense color is due to the charge transfer from oxygen to manganese, but didn't said the reason for temperature dependent paramagnetism.
So, I thought for a while and thought about the Curie's Law.

> Magnetization of a paramagnetic material is inversely proportional to the absolute temperature T
>
> $M$ = $C$ $\frac{B_0}{T}$

Is this the correct reason for it? If not what is the reason?

Comment: Curie's law applies when the species has unpaired electrons - which there are none in KMnO4, so it can't be that. Rather the weak paramagnetism is normally explained by the [Van Vleck mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Vleck_paramagnetism), which requires a low lying excited state - and we know there is such a state due to the purple colour of the ion.

Comment: Related question for pot. dichromate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115841/magnetic-properties-of-potassium-dichromate